# Knob dial with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hello I'm trying to build something like a "safe knob dialer". I've found here on SO a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775181/raphael-js-drag-rotation-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer) about rotating a line around a center.

I've modified above code, with this result:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/miasrl/yfd9kyja/3/)

However, it's not working as I would like, because (rightly) one can rotate the dialer only if drag starts from the red rectangle made with:

```
var needle = paper.path("M 125 25, L125,0").attr({stroke: '#b00', 'stroke-width': 12}).attr({opacity: 0.5});
```

The shifting angle is calculated by summing the two angle, the first between the center and the current mouse point:

```
var newA = Raphael.angle(dialCenter, dialCenter, mouseX, mouseY);
```

and the second between the center and the current endpoint of the line ("needle"):

```
var needleA = Raphael.angle(dialCenter, dialCenter, needle.getPointAtLength(needle.getTotalLength())['x'], needle.getPointAtLength(needle.getTotalLength())['y']);
```

If I set the drag listener on the filled circle "needle1" (the red one covering with low alpha the dialer png image) instead of the line "needle", I can rotate the knob dragging from any point of the knob:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/miasrl/yfd9kyja/4/)

But, obviously, it cannot retains the starting angle. How can I have a correct behavior, like the one using the small line "needle" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can store and use the offset via dragstart and dragend to get the same behaviour.

[uppdated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swippen/7n57ekv0/1/)

```
setOffset = function (e) {
    var mouseX = (e.offsetX == undefined) ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;
    var mouseY = (e.offsetY == undefined) ? e.layerY : e.offsetY;
    var newA = Raphael.angle(dialCenter, dialCenter, mouseX, mouseY);
    angleOffset =  newA -needleMemory;
}

storeNeedle = function(e) {
    var mouseX = (e.offsetX == undefined) ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;
    var mouseY = (e.offsetY == undefined) ? e.layerY : e.offsetY;
    var newA = Raphael.angle(dialCenter, dialCenter, mouseX, mouseY);
        needleMemory = newA - angleOffset;
}


var startDrag = function () {
    setOffset(event);
}, dragger = function (dx, dy) {
    moveNeedle(event);
}, endDrag = function () {
    storeNeedle(event);
};
```

And update the rotation

Is that what you are looking for?